# Why does the code "x++ && y++;" work in C without a control operator?

Tags: c, math, operators, logical-operators

I was looking for ways to cut down my line usage and came across this and it seems to work fine. I can't find any info on it on the web can someone explain what is going on? Assuming it would even run, I would still expect x++ to evaluate to false and therefore y would not increase in value. But it does!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(void)
{
    int     x;
    int     y;

    x = 4;
    y = 7;
    x++ && y++;
    printf("%d\n%d", x, y);
    return (0);
}
>> 5 
   8
```

Edit: I have a function limit of 25 lines per function for my project this is why I have to cut down a few lines.

Edit 2: all my code is subject to a strict syntax and format checker, the checker bans "x++,y++;" and any other multi line statement so I was just looking for a 'hack' to cut off one line from my program and had no idea why ^^ worked for me! Thanks fo all the responses!

Comment: In this program, `x++` will evaluate to 4, which is nonzero, and therefore "true".

Comment: Also, nowadays "cutting down your line usage" is generally considered bad style.

Comment: *"I was looking for ways to cut down my line usage"* Unless you're doing code golf, please don't make this a goal. Focus instead on writing clean code that is easy to understand.

Comment: I have had to cut down lines to satisfy my project requirements of 25 lines per function, I would not be doing it unless I had to!

Comment: x++ && y++; this line  computes to true or false, any val different from zero is true. if you replace  `x=0`, you will get `x=1  and  y=7`. since the first cond is false.

Comment: "I have had to cut down lines to satisfy my project requirements of 25 lines per function" then split your function into smaller functions??

Comment: THis is an X-Y problem - you would do better posting your complete solution and asking how to reduce the line count to 25 or less.  The truth is however that a "line" has no semantic meaning in C (other than `//` comments) - you could place at your code on one line if you wanted to.  It  is the _number of statements_ and _complexity_ your  coding-standard should be concerned with.  Such rules are normally imposed for reasons of readability and maintainability - neither of which is served by this statement.  It is misguided at best, and downright dangerous at worst.

Comment: Really though why would you expect `x++` to evaluate to false!?

Comment: If you want to increment two variables in one line you can use the comma operator: `x++, y++;`. Or you can just use a semicolon, C really doesn't care much about whitespace, you can just put `x++; y++;` on a single line if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical operators `&&` and `||` uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

For both the left-hand side is *always* evaluated. For `&&` if the left-hand side is "true" then the right-hand side is also evaluated. For `||` it's the opposite, if the left-hand side is "false" then the right-hand side is evaluated.

And in C anything that is non-zero is "true". Only zero is "false".

Comment: Okay thanks this makes sense, so as long as my x never has a value of 0 my expression will work as expected.

Comment: @ZakStucke : No the expression does not work as you expect - or at least not as you expected it to work in your question: _" expect x++ to evaluate to false and therefore y would not increase in value"_.  If you expext both sides to be evaluated it would be far clearer to just write `x++, y++ ;` or `x++; y++ ;`.  Your "solution" has no merit whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry I meant works as expected as in both values will be incremented by one unless x initially equals 0. Also, due to my code being rigourously checked by a format checker I was not able to use x++,y++; as commas are banned. Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 1):

The *spirit* of the 25 lines per function rule is really there for scalability and clarity; you ought to strive to conform to it by breaking up a long function into separate component functions rather than trying to *golf* your code by such contrivances as you cite in your question.

With the expression `x++ && y++`, `y++` is only evaluated if `x++` is non-zero, and note that `x++` evaluates to the initial value of `x`.

Note you could reduce your program to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     for (int x = 4, y = 7; x++ && y++, printf("%d\n%d", x, y); ) break;
}
```

which is nice as you have 24 lines left!? Note that the compiler is required to insert an implicit `return 0;` in the case of the function `main`.